# How can i get bone global axis rotate

Tags: python, scripting

Below code is just get bone euler_Angles.

```
import bpy
pb = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone001"]
rotate_x = pb.rotation_euler.x
rotate_y = pb.rotation_euler.y
rotate_z = pb.rotation_euler.z
```

But this angle show local axis.

And in blender, if bone rotate on global axis, properties shown rotate values as local.

How can i get global axis rotate?

Comment: From the world space matrix in dupe answer `global_rot_euler = matrix_final.to_euler()`  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone

Comment: also please don't ask the same question twice. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136455/how-to-get-posebone-global-rotate